# Create my custom Imputer for categorical variables sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataset with a lot of categorical values missing and i would like to make a custom imputer which will fill the empty values with a value equal to `"no-variable_name"`.

For example if a column `"Workclass"` has a `Nan` value, replace it with `"No Workclass"`.

I do it like this

```
X_train['workclass'].fillna("No workclass", inplace = True)
```

But I would like to make an `Imputer`, so I can pass it in a pipeline.

Comment: It looks like sklearn already has a [SimpleImputer class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) that does what you want. If it is missing something, then you can always inherit from it.

Comment: Yes they helped a lot! I just checked them because I was a little busy. Thanks you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a custom transformer using [`TransformerMixin`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.TransformerMixin.html). Here's a simple example how to define a simple transformer an include it in a pipeline:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'workclass':['class1', np.nan, 'Some other class', 'class1', 
                                np.nan, 'class12', 'class2', 'class121'], 
                   'color':['red', 'blue', np.nan, 'pink',
                            'green', 'magenta', np.nan, 'yellow']})
# train test split of X
df_train = df[:3]
df_test = df[3:]

print(df_test)

  workclass    color
3    class1     pink
4       NaN    green
5   class12  magenta
6    class2      NaN
7  class121   yellow
```

The idea will be to fit using the `df_train` dataframe, and replicate the transformations on `df_test`. We could define our custom transformation class inheriting from `TransformerMixin`:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin

class InputColName(TransformerMixin):

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.fill_with = X.columns
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return np.where(X.isna(), 'No ' + self.fill_with, X)
```

Then include it in your pipeline (just using `InputColName` here to keep the example simple) and fit it with the training data:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
  ('inputter', InputColName())
])
pipeline.fit(df_train)
```

Now if we try transforming with unseen data:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(pipeline.transform(df_test), columns=df.columns))

      workclass     color
0        class1      pink
1  No workclass     green
2       class12   magenta
3        class2  No color
4      class121    yellow
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customise the `simpleImputer` like this!

```py
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

class customImputer(SimpleImputer):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.fill_value = ['No '+c for c in X.columns]
        return super().fit(X, y)


df = pd.DataFrame({'workclass': ['classA', 'classB', np.NaN],
                   'fruit': ['apple',np.NaN,'orange']})
df

#   workclass   fruit
#0  classA  apple
#1  classB  NaN
#2  NaN orange

customImputer(strategy='constant').fit_transform(df)

#array([['classA', 'apple'],
#       ['classB', 'No fruit'],
#       ['No workclass', 'orange']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom function and call it using [`FunctionTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html):

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

def custom_fillna(X):
    return X.fillna('NONE')

custom_imputer = FunctionTransformer(custom_fillna)
custom_imputer.transform(X)
```